How to change styles (style group) for a LayerGroup
I made a LayerGroup Name 'basemap' which includes layerA and layerB.
When I try to style it, I found the params 'styles' does not work.
 var baseMapLyr = new ol.layer.Tile({
        name: 'basemap',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://' + serverIp + '/geoserver/hygz/wms?',
            params: {
                'LAYERS': 'basemap',        
                'styles': 'basemap_day',//the other styles is 'basemap_dusk'
            },       
            ratio: 1,
            serverType: 'geoserver'
        })
    });

The error message:
<ServiceException> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableExceptionNo Style with name basemap_day found for LayerGroup basemap </ServiceException>

I wonder how can i change the styles for the LayerGroup,Just like a regular layer.

You can't layer groups are opaque, you can request each layer and style pair though

@lan Turton  Can I post the params 'SLD':'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/styles/basemap_day.sld'  to style layergroup ? Just like this https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/GSIP-161

Layer Groups work a little differently. When you define your layer group, each layer in the layer group can have a style, but you can't just apply a style to a layer group (since styles only really apply to one layer at a time)
For layer groups you are going to need to define a set of Layer Group Styles in your GeoServer - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html#layer-group-styles
These allow you to choose individual styles for each of your layers in your layer group, and then name that as a style, which you can then reference using 'style' as per normal.
Here's a partial clip from one of our layer groups. The section at the top is the standard style, and at the bottom you can see the Layer Group Style. We can call this layer group either with no style (and get the one at the top) or with style=ozs_group_night to get the bottom one.

